# How to use set-header with a variable concatenated with req.hdr()

Tags: haproxy

I am using set-header to rename an incoming header from an existing one.  My problem is that in addition to renaming the header using req.hdr(my-old-header-name) I want to concatenate the interpreted value from the req.hdr() function with another static value (Bearer).

```
http-request set-header Authorization %[req.hdr(my-old-header-name)] if some-condition-applies
```

I want to be able to add a value "Bearer " in front of the interpreted %[req.hdr(my-old-header-name)] so that it ends up looking like this: `Authorization: Bearer my-old-header-value-interpreted-from-req-hdr`

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to make it work with `replace-header` as following:

`http-request replace-header Authorization (.*) Bearer\ \1 if some_condition_applies`

This basically takes the value of the Authorization header and prefixes it with `Bearer`.